# How to detect MouseDown on any non-TextBox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus, numericupdown

TextBoxes and NumericUpDowns have the odd property of not allowing you to deselect them once they are selected. When my user selects a NumericUpDown and clicks else-where on the form, the NumericUpDown should be deselected.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. Currently I am just handling the MouseDown event of all other controls on the form (like the panels and actual form itself) and just calling the Focus method of a random label to remove the focus from the NumericUpDown. However, this cannot be applied to menu items or scrollbars.

There must be a better way to do this. The user may want to scroll the panel instead of the NumericUpDown and intuitively click the Panel and then use the scroll-wheel, but currently that would scroll the NumericUpDown instead, since it still has focus.

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Problem still unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Panel Control is a Non-Focusable control. Therefore clicking on Panel will NOT remove focus from TextBox or NumericUpDown Countrol.

The workaround can be, place a button on panel and move it away from view for example setting its x = -100 and y = -100. Do NOT set visible = false.

Now whenever user clicks on Panel (Panel_Click event) set focus (Button.Focus()) to that button. In this way panel will be scrollable through scroll-wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the numeric box within a panel of some sort and then do

```
panel1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(panel1_MouseHover);

private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericUpDown1.Focused)
            {
                panel1.Focus();
            }
        }
```

I tested it and it works.!

Comment: I'm not sure how this really helps? Maybe I'm missing something but I kind of want the opposite. If the mouse clicks anywhere else on the screen the NumericUpDown should become unfocused.

Comment: yes that is what it does, when you move away from the numeric textbox it loses focus, you can even change the on hover to click or something but it does what you want. Im not sure how it doesnt help you

Comment: If I have the NumericUpDown selected and then click a panel or label for example, the NumericUpDown is still selected. I'm not sure what your code solves but the problem still exists.

Comment: if you scroll your mouse over the panel away from the numeric box then the focus is shifted to the panel. Ill see if i can send you a video cast of it.

Comment: Yeah but only if scroll slowly. Also I don't want it to automatically deselect when it leave's the NumericUpDown's bounds. I only want it to deselect when clicking elsewhere in the application.